# THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. On required modules

Tags: javascript, three.js, browserify

is there any known issue with requiring a Object3D ??? consider the following code

this works

```
...
// THREE is imported globally somewhere else

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200), material);

console.dir(mesh) // -> THREE.Mesh

scene.add(mesh);

...
```

this doesnt work

Character.ts

```
export class Character {

    create() {

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true});
        return new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200), material);

    }

}
```

app.ts

```
import {Character} from "./Character.js;

var mesh = (new Character).create();

console.dir(mesh) // -> THREE.Mesh

scene.add(mesh);
```

error

**app.js:8861 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.**

im using browserify

THREE.js version r78

Comment: We can't see, so it must be asked: can you import something without three.js dependency from `Character.js`? Next, can you create another class in `Character.js` that depends on the `Character` class, that you can successfully import elsewhere?

Comment: @gallygator i just showed a fragment, three js has been added globally on the script.. so it is available everywhere. the thing is if u take a close look at the comment in the app.ts "i am newing up the class `(new Character).create()` and it is in the console it shows it is a THREE.Mesh ... however adding the same object to the scene.. pop up that error message..

Comment: Seems to me you have a couple sol'n challenges: 1) code cannot by easily duped or error recreated by others, 2) the problem may be with browserify, three.js, 3) the problem may be with three.js, typescript. I can only recommend simplifying back to some minimal case to get it to work and confirm which constituent is resulting in error. Then, you can report the bug with some demo repo.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this -- my problem was that I was including `three.js` twice in my project. I included it myself, and I was also using a library that included `three.js`. This creates some errors due to object constructors being overwritten, and I think that's what caused my error. Consider the example below (swiped this code from [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6362#issuecomment-98230851)):

```
window.MyObject = function () {};
var v1 = new window.MyObject();
console.log( 'first object instanceof:', v1 instanceof window.MyObject ); // true

window.MyObject = function () {};
var v2 = new window.MyObject();
console.log( 'second object instanceof:', v2 instanceof window.MyObject ); // true
console.log( 'first object instanceof:', v1 instanceof window.MyObject ); // false!
```

Comment: thanks man.. but in the end i found what i did wrong.... it was due to the code is async ... and the console tricked me... if i console.log it will log the object on the current state... if some lines more down the line the object changes.. that first console log also will change.... so i felt.. how the line 1 console .log this... and the file 500 console log also log the same object.... then i figured it out... it was the console.log cheating on me...